# Find matches in across multiple columns in another table

Tags: excel

So I have a excel document where I need to lookup values in one sheet from another sheet. I need it to lookup multiple columns in the other sheet to find a matching value.

This is sorta what my tables look like, I'm trying to find values from the top table in the bottom table

So my original formula looked like

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(A:A,ROW()),'Other-Sheet'!$B$3:$D$500,2,FALSE)),"INACTIVE","ACTIVE")
```

But that didn't work, then I tried

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$B:$B, 1, FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$C:$C, 1, FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$D:$D, 1, FALSE)))), "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE")
```

Hey silly mistake, I fixed it by just changing the `AND` in the second formula to an `OR`

Comment: Hey silly mistake, I fixed it by just changing the AND in the second formula to a OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed up your spreadsheet by changing the references to a table reference that will resize with your dataset rather than checking the entire columns. As your sheet gets bigger this can weigh down on the performance immensely.

`=IF(OR(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$B:$B, 1, FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$C:$C, 1, FALSE))), NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A251, 'Other-Sheet'!$D:$D, 1, FALSE)))), "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE")`